# can you use castle dynamic proxies on web services references?

Tags: c#, .net, castle, castle-dynamicproxy, dynamic-proxy

Is it possible to create a dynamic proxy on the a web service reference that has been added to a visual studio project?

I've added the web service reference in the normal way and tried to create a dynamic proxy using castle to wrap the method invocation in a try/catch to translate any SoapExceptions, but on running it I'm getting a lot of errors around non serializable classes?

has anyone done anything like this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes, this should be possible.
What errors are you getting? Which classes you're trying to serialize that won't serialize?

It's probably better to discuss it on [Castle users group](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users)